# Is あの兵に plural or singular?

Tags: translation, meaning, word-usage

Full sentence:生者は死なないあの兵士に意味を与えるまで 
I read it as : The living won't die until those soliders are given meaning

Is it okay or is it about a single solider?

Comment: The 意味をりえるまで part makes no sense.  Could you double-check?

Comment: You're right, I edited now

Answer (score 2):

Unless the context clearly indicates otherwise, people would interpret this あの兵士 as one specific soldier. 生者 can be either singular or plural, purely depending on the context.

<sub>(This is a copy of *Attack on Titan*, and fans seem to guess あの兵士 refers to one specific character in the story.)</sub>

Comment: So あの兵士  can be about more people than one or is it their guess?  Contextually the character did say omae tachi in the past to refer to numerous soliders

Comment: @Noa By "in the past", do you mean [this scene](https://blog.goo.ne.jp/muna73/e/d905850a8ec7b89be215e612d21d83b2) in Chapter 80? Then **this** あの兵士 clearly refers to the multiple, dead, unnamed soldiers. However, the copy you asked about appeared dozens of chapters later, and it's unlikely that it refers to the same group of soldiers. I may be wrong since I don't know the detailed story, but fans on the net seem to think **this** あの兵士 refers to リヴァイ who is supposed to be dead at this point.

Comment: In chapter 112, just before his supposed death. The context is that Levi's mission in life is to survive so he can prove his dead comrades didn't die in vain. so i don't think it refers to him but to the soliders

Comment: @Noa Okay, anyway, you cannot grammatically determine whether あの兵士 is singular or plural. It purely depends on the context, and you know the context better than me. If you believe 生者 refers to Lewi and あの兵士 refers to his dead colleagues, that also makes sense, so go ahead.